# What is the fixed vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am dealing with Linear Algebra, and face with below statement:

"for the regular matrices $A$, you can just find the fixed vector to compute $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}A^m$"

What is the fixed vector?

Comment: The term does not ring a bell. Can you provide more context?

Comment: um.. first, I am learning the Markov Chain and what the transition matrix is and how to figure out the existence of $\lim A^m$ and how to compute it with diagonalization. But this procedure looks become a bit easier if the $A$ is regular

Comment: for example, my solution provides fixed vector of A = {{1/3, 1/3,1},{2/3, 0, 0}, {0, 2/3, 0}} as {{9/19}, {6/19}, {4/19}}

Comment: "fixed vector of $A$" might mean [row] eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: @angryavian thx. you were right. there's a theorem in the book I just find : for the regular transition matrix, $\lim A^m$ equals to the eigenvector of A corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: @Daschin the limit should be a matrix, while the eigenvector is a column. Also an arbiritary non-singular(regular) matrix need not have any of its eigenvalues equal to 1